# Excel: Selecting optimal values in a column w.r.t some other column

Tags: excel

Unfortunately I have to do this in Excel...

I have a table like this:

```
A   B
3   10
4   11
7   9
5   6
3   9
```

I now need to average the largest possible selection of values of column B that together have a value larger than or equal to some predefined value K in column A.

For example, if K = 7, the optimal choice of elements from column B would be those of the first and second row, because we get an average in column B that is larger than any other average we get from selecting rows such that their sum is >= 7 *in column A*.

Comment: The average required is of 2 values only? If you need maximal average, then by definition a 2 value averagevwill be derived

Comment: @Guy Lozon My table is way larger so in reality I do not know how many elements will be required. I guess the algorithm would be: 1) Rank values from column B by value 2) Select the top M elements from column B where M guarantees that their sum in column A is >= K and then 3) Average those

Comment: I don't understand.  You have four values in column B that are `>=` 7.  If you want the highest average, won't it always be the average of the two highest values.  And if you want the average of values `>= 7`, then just use `AVERAGEIF`.  Otherwise, please provide an example where the `optimal` will be an average of more than two values.

Comment: Mathematically: I have the data X with N rows and 2 columns. I need Y = maximum average in terms of column 2 over all possible subsets of {1,...,N} that satisfy the condition that the sum within column A of this subset is >= K

Comment: I think I was unclear about the fact that while we will always pick the top values of column B, we don't know how many are needed to ensure that they sum up to >= K in column A

Comment: Then why not just the top value, given your example.  `Average(11) = 11` and `11=>7`.   By the way, I will not get notified that you have responded to a comment unless you tag that comment with @myname (no spaces).  I just happened to see it this time.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks for the hint. Yes, we do choose the top M values of column B, but we don't know M. The criterion is related to the corresponding values in column A. Because maybe we need 3 elements to ensure that their sum within column A is >= K = 7